# I'm trying to make a code that gives you admin and assigns it to you, this is the code;

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def admin(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.guild.create_role(mentionable=True, permissions=Permissions.all())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the problem here? Just the code does not help us. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I found is with the imports. Try doing `from discord.ext import commands` instead of `from discord.ext.commands import Bot`. I don't have much experience with creating roles, however, that may be the problem. Please comment on this message if you require any more support!

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def admin(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name=“Admin”, mentionable=True, permissions=Permissions.all())
    await ctx.add_role(“Admin”)
```

Would this work?